# Converting user input (which is in byte format) to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, byte

## TL;DR

I guess what I'm looking for is to convert a `string[]` to a `byte[]`, without actually converting the contents of `string[]` to bytes, as they are already bytes.

I have the following code:

```
public static bool isHex(String hex) {
    if(hex.Substring(0, 2) == "0x")
        hex = hex.Substring(2, (hex.Length - 2));
    return Regex.IsMatch(hex, @"\A\b[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z");
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.Write("Input bytes: ");
    String input = Console.Readline();

    String[] valueArray = input.Split(new string[] { "\\x" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    for(int i = 0; i > valueArray.Length; i++)
        if(!isHex(valueArray[i]))
            usage(args[1] + " is not valid hex", 6);
}
```

Which gets user input, and checks if it is valid hex.

Lets say the user inputs `\x00\xff\x12`, I was wondering how I could convert this to a byte array.

However, I don't want to convert the string to bytes, since the bytes are in the string (\x**00**\x**ff**\x**12**), but I want to insert those values into a byte array.

I don't want to convert the array elements themselves to bytes (i.e `["00", "FF", "12"]` to `["30", "30", "66", "66", "31", "32"]`, since `["00", "FF", "12"]` is valid hex).

Comment: If you can break up the input into pairs of hex digits then `Int32.Parse(input, NumberStyles.HexNumber,)` will get you an `int` which you can cast. If you are likely to get bad input you could use `Int32.TryParse` instead,

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I modified your code, the byte array you need is `byteArray`

By the way, your loop condition is wrong, it should be `i < valueArray.Length`

I'm not sure if it's what you want

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Input bytes: ");
            String input = Console.ReadLine();
            String[] valueArray = input.Split(new string[] { "\\x" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            List<byte> byteArray = new List<byte>();
            for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.Length; i++) {
                int ret = -1;
                string hex = valueArray[i];
                if (hex.StartsWith("0x"))
                    hex = hex.Substring(2, hex.Length - 2);
                if (!Int32.TryParse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out ret) || ret < 0 || ret > 0xff) {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not valid hex", valueArray[i]);
                    return;
                }
                byteArray.Add((byte)ret);
            }
        }
    }
}
```